# What are the elements of a quotient space?

Tags: general-topology

What are the elements of a quotient space? Every definition I see effectively defines the elements of a quotient space as sets.  Thus, the topology on the quotient space must be defined in terms of which sets of sets are open.   But this does not square with the usual definition of the topology on the quotient space.

A simple example:  Let $X$ be the finite set of integers $\{1,2,3,...,9\}$ and let even integers be equivalent.  What are the elements of the space $X/\sim$ ?

Comment: The elements of $X/\sim$ are $\{1\},\{3\},\{5\},\{7\},\{9\},\{2,4,6,8\}$. What "usual definition of the topology on the quotient space" are you using that it "does not square" with the fact that "the topology on the quotient space must be defined in terms of which sets of sets are open"? I don't see any nonsquaring going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right, we typically formalize the quotient space $X\,/\sim$ by taking its underlying set to be the set of equivalence classes under $\sim$. So an element of $X\,/\sim$ is a subset of $X$. The topology on $X\,/\sim$, like any other topology, is determined by which subsets of $X\,/\sim$ are the open sets.

Your confusion seems to stem from the fact that an open subset of $X\,/\sim$ is a set of subsets of $X$. This is true, but it needn't worry you! Remember, to define a topology on $X\,/\sim$, we just need to say which subsets *of this set* are open.

And here's the definition: Letting $\pi:X \rightarrow X\,/\sim$ be the projection $\pi(x) = [x]$, where $[x]$ is the equivalence class of $x$ under $\sim$, we have that $Y\subseteq X\,/\sim$ is open in $X\,/\sim$ if and only if $\pi^{-1}[Y]$ is open in $X$. This makes sense, since $\pi^{-1}[Y]$ is a subset of $X$!

Comment: Thanks. My confusion concerned which sets need to be defined as open in the quotient topology, i.e. whether it is the elements of the space (which are sets), or sets of those elements (sets of sets).  If I understand correctly, the answer is "both."

Comment: To define a topology on a space, you just need to say what subsets of that space are open. Whether the elements of the space are themselves subsets of another space is irrelevant.

Answer (score 6):

Everything is a set, eventually. There is a false dichotomy between "points" and "sets". Really, what you call points are also sets, eventually (working in a formal system like ZFC). E.g. a "real number" can be defined as a Dedekind cut, which is a pair of subsets of the rationals, satisfying some axioms. So a "set of reals" in such a world view is also a set of sets. And a rational number is a set of equivalence classes of pairs of integers (in my usual definition), and every pair of integers is a set too. And integers are defined as sets as well (where $0 = \emptyset, 1 = \{\emptyset\}, 2= \{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}\},\ldots$ (And this is where it stops, as we reach the empty set). This is the nature of set theory (and topologists, at least the ones coming from general topology) really like set theory...

So yes, every "point" of $X/\sim$ is a set of points of X. So this notion is one up in the hierarchy of "everything is a set of sets". But open sets in $X / \sim$ are just sets of points of $X / \sim$, just as open sets in $X$ are just sets of points of $X$. Nothing has changed. Just conceptually, it's harder, because when reasoning formally about such spaces  we do have a more complex notation and an extra level of abstraction, sometimes.

When we say "the quotient of an interval is a circle, when we identify the endpoints", the quotient is really still (by definition) this set of classes (here all singletons and a doubleton), but we have a more simple "model" (another familiar space like the unit circle in the plane) that we can prove (using the formal definitions, really) to be homeomorphic to it. And we identify homeomorphic spaces for all practical purposes (in topology). When I started topology, we had to prove such things first in a formal way, so we knew how to do it, and know when to trust the intuition one gets that way, so later we could step over the more obvious parts of such proofs. But I think it is good to have both the formal and less formal view of things.